# "refusing to merge unrelated histories" failure while pulling to recovered repository

Tags: git, github

I come up with a problem about Git push.

It worked successfully before, but it failed this time. In the beginning, I am in my master `MINGW64 /d/javasoft/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/webapps/MyNote (master)`, and then,

- I use `git remote add origin` to relate my remote origin, but it alerts that `fatal: remote origin already exists.`
- then, I use `git remote rm origin` (Someone told me to), and it's OK.
- then, I use `git remote add origin https://github.com/***/***.git` again. It's OK.
- then, I use `git push -u origin master` ( I tried `git push origin master`, but I lost my local whole `.git` for some reason before, so I guess it may be the first time to push, and I should add `-u` ). BUT, it alerts `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/***/***.git'`
- then, someone told me that I should use `git pull origin master` before I use `push`, and I did as it. *but*, it alerted: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`.
- I found some answers in *[Git refusing to merge unrelated histories on rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories)*, but it seemed that it didn't work. In my issue, it alerted `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref –allow-unrelated-histories`

---

How can I do it? I just want to push...

Comment: Have you established why the histories have diverged?  You need to find out whether local and remote/origin have commits ahead of each other, and this if so, decide whether you will merge or rebase.

Comment: "I lost my local whole .git for some reason before". So have you started new history with just your code? That could explain what you see.

Comment: Basically, you definitely **should not** use the `–allow-unrelated-histories` flag in your case. Instead you should restore the history of your code, so that the last commit from the origin history you have in your code is its parent, then merge should give correct result

Comment: may I ask that how can I restore the history of my code... ( finanlly I rebuilt my remote and local repo, and it was solved, but it paid. Part of my github history has gone..). I apparently do not understand history and conflict of git very well

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This cannot be answered shortly.

**Warning**: You **should not** use the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag unless you know what unrelated history is and are sure you need it. The check was introduced just to prevent disasters when people merge unrelated projects by mistake.

*As far as I understand*, in your case **the following has happened**:

You have cloned a project at some point `1`, and made some development to point `2`. Meanwhile, project has evolved to some point `3`.

[image]

Then you for some reason lost your local .git subdirectory - which contained all your history from `1` to `2`. You managed to restore the current state though.

[image]

But now it does not have any history - it looks like the whole project has appeared out of nowhere. If you ask Git to merge them it will not be able to say where your changes are, so it can add them to remote project, as far as I understand it will just report massive add/add conflicts.

**You should** now find back that commit `1` from the remote history where you have cloned the project (I assume you did not pull after that; if you did then you should instead look for the last commit you have pulled). Then you should modify your history so that is starts from that commit 1, and then Git will be able to merge correctly (with pull for example).

So, the steps (assuming you are now in your restored commit without history):

- estimate where is the commit `1` you have cloned from as some `1?`, based on commit time for example
- run `git diff _1?_..HEAD`, and read carefully. Make sure that the difference contains only edits which you have made. If it contains more then you should have picked a bit wrong `1?` and need to adjust it and repeat this step
- after you have found the commit `1`. You should make it your parent; do `git --reset --soft _1_`, and then `git commit`.

[image]

Now it looks like you have cloned from `1`, then made one commit with all your changes. Your intermediate history is lost anyway with your older `.git` directory, but now you can run your `git pull` - it will merge correctly.

Comment: I've found it necessary to use the flag when importing an existing repository to a newly created repository in Github.

Comment: It didn't directly solves my problem, but it was great learn more about it! Now I'm feeling more confident about resolving my issue, thanks!

Comment: i had a different issue... first **[fork](https://github.com/cauerego/oh-my-bash-absimple) on github**. clone it. add original source as remote. pull. **my fix: use fetch upstream and merge on github itself**. not a single issue! whenever i tried `allow-unrelated-histories` before or after this fix, it always gives me conflicts which evidently shouldn't exist.

Comment: Even if you success in `--allow-unrelated-histories`, your `git blame` (i.e files histories) will no longer work, it'll always point to the other `unrelated` history, which is mostly useless.

Answer (score -4):

Try to commit the changes to the local repository efore pushing them onto GitHub.

It may solve the issue (I had a similar issue).