# Git is refusing to merge unrelated histories. What are 'unrelated histories'?

Tags: git, git-pull

I created a local repo with `git remote origin https:////...`.

Then, in that local repo, I made a new text file → `git add newfile.txt` → `git commit -m "..."` → `git pull origin master` → ERROR!

"refusing to merge unrelated histories".

What are unrelated histories?

What are related histories?

Comment: What did you do to setup your local repository? Did you run `git init` + `git remote add ...`? What is the remote and what are you trying to do?

Comment: A branch points to a commit. A non-root commit has one or more parents and each parent commit has its own one or more parents. When two branches don't have any common ancestor in their histories, they are unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I just wanted to know what 'unrelated history' not to resolve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git refusing to merge unrelated histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories)

Comment: There is a better and more inclusive answer here          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Comment: `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` .See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Comment: I made an edit guessing how you got into the place of being connected with a repo without branches. I'm hoping I guessed correctly.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

I think you have committed in the remote repository, and when you pull, this error happens.

Use this command:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge origin origin/master
```

Comment: i suggest reading at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761024/refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-failure-while-pulling-to-recovered-repos

Comment: This solution is helpful, but note that the OP actually wanted ***understanding*** and not a fix.  Therefore, the comments threaded in the question above are actually more helpful.  (I had the same issue; I knew how to fix it, but never really knew what "it" was... I didn't understand what "unrelated histories" actually meant.)

Comment: The link that @jitter points to gives a perfect & well-detailed answer.

Comment: This worked when I had to create a new GitHub repo with License commit and merge with my project that was already old.  I guess the best solution is to push first, then add other stuff.  But in case you make my mistake, anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: This is a nice answer but for more details you can check out this question    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Comment: I may be wrong. But I think your second command should be `git merge origin/master`

Comment: If you get `fatal: couldn't find remote ref master`, try it with "main" instead of "master", since your branch might perhaps not be called like this.

Comment: It's incredible how many git commands/subcommands exist — for each and every tiny little problem, there is _always_ a not-very-well-documented git functionality that can be activated to "fix everything". No wonder people stick with Git and give up on the other alternatives (FOSS or commercial)...

Comment: [As previously noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272492/git-is-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-what-are-unrelated-histories#comment87158172_45272685), this question does NOT help to build understanding of what an unrelated history is, and when it is needed.  It should be augmented by giving an example of when this command should be used, perhaps using the OP's question as an example. It should also clearly describe when this command should *not* be used.

Comment: In particular, the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64613177/1048186), despite having far fewer upvotes, feels cleaner to me.  Why do we need to both pull and merge?  Fetching the remote branch and then merging, while checking on the local repo as I describe in the second answer feels safer.

Answer (score 44):

I ran into a similar problem where I brought in a branch from a second remote and wanted to merge with a branch from the first remote. This is different from the existing answers as I'm not using --allow-unrelated-histories on the pull, but on the merge.

```
git fetch origin master
git checkout master
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories myfunnybranch
```

This fetches and checks out the master branch and merges the myfunnybranch into it.  By using `git fetch` rather than `git pull` we distinguish between bringing code to our machine, and performing the difficult merge.

### When NOT to perform an unrelated history merge

**Warning**: An "unrelated history" is a history that does not go back to a common source. In other words, `myfunnybranch` and `master` are derived from two completely different repositories.

If the two repositories are very similar or have lots of files in common, **there is a good chance that one of the repos lost its history somewhere along the way**.  Whether or not this is the case, its probably best to avoid two histories leading to the same set of files.  Instead, you'd like to keep the longer history and have a single commit bringing in any changes from the other repository. To achieve this goal, checkout the repository with the longer history and copy the files of the other one in, which should produce a small commit with few changes, which `git status` and `git diff` will summarize for you before you make the commit with `git commit`.  For more details, [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761024/refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-failure-while-pulling-to-recovered-repos), which was mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272492/git-is-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-what-are-unrelated-histories#comment81604392_45272685) on another answer to this question.

In the OP's case (which was elaborated on in an edit to the question), there is likely no need for an unrelated merge.  Perhaps the OP didn't clone the repo, or perhaps someone else pushed to the empty repo before the OP made their initial commit.  Either way, since the OP is editing only a single file, it would be better to simply clone the repo fresh, copy the new file into the cloned repo, and add, commit, and push there.

### When TO perform an unrelated history merge

You would only want to merge unrelated histories if the two repositories indeed share very little in common. For example, each repository contributes a different set of files during the merges.

In my case I wanted to merge two totally different repos that had files in different directories and I wanted to preserve the history of both of these. This was code that I thought should be together in a single repo but was originally written in two different repos.

While the OP appears to be adding a new file here, this is probably not a case where we need multiple histories.

As [P. Ent notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272492/git-is-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-what-are-unrelated-histories#comment120480678_64613177), one case where it makes sense to merge unrelated histories is when you have performed a fair bit of development locally, and there really hasn't been much development on origin/main.  If essentially **all** of the development was done locally on `myfunnybranch`, it might even make sense to run

```
git checkout myfunnybranch
git merge -s ours --allow-unrelated-histories main
```

This ignores all the work on the main branch, but keeps it in the history. Only the code in `myfunnybranch` is kept.  Now merging `myfunnybranch` back into `main` should be easy.

In cases like these, `git log --all --graph` is useful to see what your local repository looks like before you push anything.

For example, after the `git merge -s ours` command suggested above, you might find your repo to look like

```
git log --all --oneline --graph
*   6c8188b (HEAD -> myfunnybranch) Merge branch 'main' into myfunnybranch
|\
| * b93aabd (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) Initial commit on remote server
* f69e99b some work I did locally
* df5d8ae more local work
* da455d6 Initial commit that I made locally
```

In this case you could use

```
git diff 6c8188b f69e99b
```

to confirm that your most recent commit, 6c8188b, really didn't change any of the work you did locally. It will print nothing if there are no changes.

Then, merging myfunnybranch back into main will result in main matching your local development, too. This is because from the main branch's perspective, commit 6c8188b makes a whole bunch of edits bringing the branch exactly in line with the other branch.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had a repo created for me with a develop branch (with a gitignore in it). My local repo was a master branch. I set the remote origin and then pushed my master branch. I then wanted to merge the master into the nearly empty develop so they'd be in sync for further development. This did the trick.

Comment: ```l$ git merge --allow-unrelated-hisotries module-2
error: unknown option `allow-unrelated-hisotries'
usage: git merge [<options>] [<commit>...]
   or: git merge --abort
   or: git merge --continue```

Comment: @mLstudent33 There's a typo in yours. That's why it fails.

Answer (score 19):

When somehow the local `.git` subdirectory is lost, the whole project seems to appear from nowhere, as all the local changes histories were contained by `.git`. Thus, your local changes become unrelated. That is why all the changes are called *unrelated histories* then.

In this situation, `git merge or pull` request will unable to track where you made changes to add with the remote project. Hence, `" refusing to merge unrelated histories"`- error occurs.

In this situation, if you try to force merge by following commands,

`git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`

`git merge origin origin/master`

It will create a lot of conflicts, as it is not able to find the history of your local changes.

Answer (score 6):

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the one line below: You do not need to specify origin and master and all that. Atleast not in a recent version of git. I have used this command and I may have lost a small amount of code but it was nothing major for me to recode. Use at your own risk. The problem is you lose your newest code still on your PC so after running this code copy and paste the actual lines of code not just the files and do a commit/push and everything should look fine. I am by no means an git expert but when you can no longer push or pull you can use this command or recreate your git repo with your latest code you get manage to get your hands on.

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue when renaming one of the repositories in GitHub Enterprise, and then making the same former named repository as the below steps.

1. create repository `sample` in remote
2. clone it to local
3. rename remote to `old-sample`
4. create a new repository named `sample` in remote
5. try to push it from local
6. error occurred.

The weird thing is that I removed the local repository, but git tries to clone old one even if I try to clone by newly created repository URL. The clone URL is just automatically redirected to the old one, even if the new one exists in remote. I don't know if this is due to the server or local Git process.

For this reason, the error occurs because the Git process fails to compare its local commit history to the remote history.

The **unrelated histories** could tell in the above situation.

I ended up removing and renamed the old repository in remote and it was solved.

Answer (score 2):

**When Pull and Merge the Changes from the Remote Refuses Try Force Push**

```
git pull origin master
```

If the above step results in the "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories" error again, then perform a force push with the -f option:

```
git push -f origin master
```