# R Studio and Git won't sync

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to link R Studio to GitHub. In my global options, the git executable is set up to the correct git/bin folder. I've already added the github URL using these [instructions](https://happygitwithr.com/push-pull-github.html). I was able to modify the readme and that commit went through just fine. I'm now trying to commit an rmd and it just won't go through. When I click the git tab, the rmd shows up, I write a commit message, and then click commit and it says it went through, but it never shows up.

I found these [instructions](https://hansenjohnson.org/post/sync-github-repository-with-existing-r-project/) and so I'm checking the origin master to see if everything is set up properly. Here's what I get:

[image]

The https for git is correct here, as is the folder it's pulling from. I'm not a programmer generally (I'm a data analyst), so I don't know the ins and outs of this stuff. I've been hammering away at this for a few hours now and I'm just getting increasingly frustrated. Since I'm not a programmer, I'm really not clear on what's not working and why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try doing what the hints say? "Fetch origin" then pull/reset?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37937984 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/45272492. I argue that this has nothing to do with R, especially since your screen shots are from `cmd.exe`, not the RStudio IDE. (The only way that this could be related to R would be if it works fine on the command line but not from RStudio. And even then it's about the IDE, not the language.)

Comment: Since the OP's answer doesn't really explain anything, I'm voting to close a "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The following command should solve your problem.

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: I've tried that and it says that it did a "fetch_head" and that it's already up to date. I tried committing it again through the git window and it still doesn't appear on the github side.

Comment: Try to check the remote name you're trying to sync your local copy. `git remote -v`