# "Amend latest commit" in Sourcetree, creates unrelated error

Tags: git, github, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I thought `Amend last commit` in Sourcetree is just for "last commited message" and used it while commiting. But it raised the following error

[image]

I tried to pull from remote, but got "cant pull from unrelated histories".

My question is, Do `Amend last commit` does more than just a message? Why unrelated history error came?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An amend last commit would by default trigger an "behind its remote counterpart" error on `git push`, if that mast commit was previously pushed.

It changes the last commit done:

```
-x--x--x (master, origin/master)
```

Change the last commit with amend:

```
-x--x--X' (master)
     \
      x   (origin/master)
```

"can't pull from unrelated histories" can happen if the remote repository has only one commit: changing the local one means: no common ancestor.
(If not, read "[“refusing to merge unrelated histories” failure while pulling to recovered repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39783462/6309)")
You can [pull allowing for unrelated history to be merged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45272685/6309)

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge origin origin/master
```

... or you can simply, if you are the only one working on the remote repo, force the push.

```
git push --force
```