# Can I change default git configuration in order to allow merge of unrelated histories?

Tags: git

I discovered that my favourite GUI git client (Tower) does not have an option to add the `--allow-unrelated-histories` parameter to git merge.

Is there a way to enable this by default on my git configuration? How?

Ps. Luckily the client is using external git, which means that if there is a global configuration option for this it should be used.

Comment: Looking through the list of config options in the docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), there doesn't seem to be anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend changing this default. This could cause big problems for you down the road. If you need to do this as a one off you should pop into a terminal and use this answer: [Git refusing to merge unrelated histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories)

Comment: I think this might be a comment more than an answer

Comment: I am in a middle of a big repository merge work so I need to use this MANY times. Yep, in the long run I plan to remove the default config change but for the moment I would really like to have it changes so I can finish my work.

Answer (score 1):

With the standard merge script, this is not (and will not be) possible.  Per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---allow-unrelated-histories) (emphasis mine):

> **--allow-unrelated-histories**
>
> By default, git merge command refuses to merge histories that do not share a common ancestor. This option can be used to override this safety when merging histories of two projects that started their lives independently. **As that is a very rare occasion, no configuration variable to enable this by default exists and will not be added.**

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to override this default in your config.  Maybe you can do this work from the command-line, or even script it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an alias

```
merge = merge --allow-unrelated-histories
```