# Selected branches have not common commits or git refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: git, github

Recently, I have been asked by a friend to pull changes from remote repo into local. He told me that, at first, he **copied** the local repo as backup and then worked *in that repo* and pushed code to remote. Now in the **orignal repo** (from where he copied all the stuff) `git pull` was throwing this error message.

```
Can not merge two branches with unrelated history.
```

I don't know what exactly was the problem and I just want to **recreate the scenario** and generate same error message again. How can I recreate the same scenario? What are the possible reasons for above errors?

Comment: This is related, but only partly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories (in particular your Git version must be 2.9 or later to see the error at all).

Comment: You'll need to upgrade your Git to version 2.9 or later in order to reproduce it. Older versions of Git (including your 2.5.2) will merge unrelated histories without complaint.

Comment: Thaks @torek. I have updated my git to 2.10 and now I can see the same error.