# GitHub "Remote Repo" options do not exist in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github, version-control, repository

I'm having a problem with the latest Xcode where I have already configured my GitHub account, and init the .git file, but I can't find any option to create/host my repository on GitHub. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can create the repo in github from xcode? Why not have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860914/how-to-create-new-project-with-github-and-xcode?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think the previous versions has this option call "create remote repos"

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's a great source tho. Yeah I sometimes do that, but it looks so unpractical. it's like cheating.

Comment: In the left sidebar, click the boxed "x" button, right click on "remotes" and you can create a repo from there. You may need to add a github account?

Comment: @evolutionxbox dude ur amazing. put as an answer so I can give you the credit!

Comment: It was more of a guess really...