# How to change repository of GitHub on PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I created a **first** project on *PhpStorm* and pushed it to GitHub repository.After then on PhpStorm I can Update project and Commit changes easily with two buttons on Navigation bar.

Later I created **second** project on Project and also pushed it to GitHub. Now I have two projects on GitHub and on PhpStorm.

How can I change my **second** PhpStorm project to the **first** GitHub project?

Comment: you can use this command for change repository URL : `git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here`

Comment: also you can go to `VCS > Git > Remotes` and change your repository URL

Comment: @Alihossein shahabi I don't have such an option `Remotes` . I tried use this command  `git remote set-url origin  https://github.com/...`. And after this it says **push failed error**.

Comment: check to see if the URL has changed ?  With `git remote -v`

Comment: @Alihossein shahab Yes it's changed.

Comment: Ok so first run ‘git pull origin master’ and run ‘git push origin master’.test again please

Comment: @Alihossein shahab after `git pull origin master` it says `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: You can use` ‍--allow-unrelated-histories` to force the merge to happen.read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase