# issues with git push and github

Tags: git, github

I am trying to git push and I am getting the following errors:

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or 
configure a remote repository using

git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

git push <name>
```

So then I enter:

```
git push https://github.com/everest- 
software/everest-web.git
```

And I get this:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream 
branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as 
upstream, use

git push --set-upstream 
https://github.com/everest-software/everest- 
web.git master
```

After I enter that, I get this:

```
To https://github.com/everest-software/everest- 
web.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast- 
forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://github.com/everest-software/everest- 
web.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of 
your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the 
remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git 
push --help' for details.
```

What do I do?

Comment: Is this a new GitHub repository? What files already exist in it?

Comment: To add to the above question, did you _clone_ your current local repository, or is this completely new code which you then want to push to GitHub for the first time?

Comment: yes new repo. Just license and read me

Comment: You seem to have [the exact same problem as another person posted earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549407/i-cannot-publish-my-vs-code-repository-to-github/51549513#51549513). Read the answer I posted there as well as the comments for suggestions about how to solve it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen new code that I want to push

Comment: Please follow GitHub's documentation for how to handle this: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ ... this question is also probably a duplicate of something else.

Comment: Those steps work until the last step. The push origin master doesn't work.

Comment: This is my output:To https://github.com/everest-software/everest-web.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/everest-software/everest-web.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: @chody Read the link I gave above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it says that your current branch is behind master branch.So you need to git pull first to make your branch tip in level with master branch.

Comment: From https://github.com/everest-software/everest-web
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: thats my output from pulling