# My tree is cutted

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I started work before cloning or pulling and this is the result

The problem is I have two branches with the same name "master" one of them on the local side and one on the git remote.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: @JoshLee completely i can't because i can not merge master to master which they are the same brunch

Comment: I think [Git refusing to merge unrelated histories on rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase) might be helpful, specifically the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option (It can be used with `git pull` in addition to `merge` and `rebase`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have anything important on the remote repository you could force push your local history `git push --force origin master`. Note that other people should then clone again the repository to avoid history conflicts.

Comment: $ git push --force master origin/master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Oh, I had it the other way arround. It should be `git push -f <remote> <branch>`. For your case it should be `git push -f origin/master master`. Hope it works!

Comment: Then you can use `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`. This will create a merge commit of both branches, but you'll have the hole history there.

Comment: I don't have tow branches I have just one. So I can't merge

Comment: But you do have two brances, master and origin/master. In git they are two branches of two repositories (remote and local).