# Merging split history in git

Tags: git, rebase

I have been toying with rebase a bit, trying to split and combine history as described here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace

Here is my test repository with split history:
https://github.com/defufna/split-history

[image]

Note that "initial commit" and "Added description" commits both point to the same tree. What I'm trying to do is merge these two histories (while maintaining merges). I used this:

```
git rebase --rebase-merges --onto history 94da9b0f
```

This works, but I'm getting a conflict at 084dae5. This is a merge that resolves modify/delete conflict, and it requires me to manually resolve this conflict.

I am doing this in preparation for much larger repo merge, where I will have to do something similar but with 50k commits, so I would like to avoid manual conflict resolution. 
I am aware that git replace could solve my problem, but I'm curious if it is possible to do it without replacement. I would also like to keep sha values of commits in history branch.

**Edit:**

So I've managed to do what I want, but I'm not sure how good this idea is.
I've added -i to rebase, and when I got todo file, I've changed every

```
merge -C 9751be2 Merge # Merge
```

line into:

```
exec git checkout `git commit-tree '9751be2^{tree}' -p HEAD -p refs/rewritten/Merge -m Merge`
```

I'm basically telling git whenever it encounters a merge to reuse tree from original merge.

It works as expected (for now), but it's a lot slower. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You might need `--allow-unrelated-histories` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Comment: Apperently rebase does not support that parameter. Also git does not complain about unrelated histories, rebase completes correctly and as expected after I resolve conflict. I'm just trying to find a way that wont produce a conflict.

Comment: Why do you need to rebase? Could you use a merge instead?

Comment: Note that any "merge preserving" rebase (including the fancy new `--rebase-merges` that replaces the old sort-of-defective `-p` / `--preserve-merges`) actually works by *re-performing* the merge. Any conflicts you had to solve then, you may well have to solve again. While `git rerere` will help with low level conflicts, it will do nothing for high level (whole-file) conflicts such as modify/delete conflicts.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: `--allow-unrelated-histories` is only needed with `git merge` when there is no merge base. It tells the merge strategy to use the empty tree (https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) as the merge base commit. Since this is a rebase, not a merge, that particular trick doesn't apply here.

Comment: @torek according to the image they have no merge base.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Right, but *this is a rebase!* (Perhaps the appropriate emphasis on *merge* is missing in my phrase "only needed with ... merge".)

Comment: @torek ah right. Then there may not be a way round the OP's issue of many conflicts.

Comment: Do you need the files on your future master be exactly the same as they are now?

Comment: Yes, It wouldn't be ok for them to differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note that "initial commit"[94da] and "Added description"[c00e] commits both point to the same tree

> Is there a better way to do this?

Much.

```
git replace --graft 94da c00e^
git filter-branch master
```

and you're done.

`git rebase` exists to re-apply changes onto different base content, producing snapshots with new content.  You already have all the snapshots you want, you only need to rewire the ancestry.  `git replace --graft` does it locally, allowing you to experiment casually.  `git filter-branch` exists to bake in rewired ancestry while applying any super-easy content changes -- but you don't even have any of those. You just want to rewire the `master` history.

Comment: Can I keep sha's in history branch? I'm fine with rebased commits changing shas.

Comment: Yes, you could equivalently rewire `6898` and `4c2b`'s ancestry to `c00e`.