# Impossible to merge branch: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-fetch

I created a new remote repo ('myRepo') on Git.
I checked the checkbox 'add a README.md', which also make a commit on this 'myRepo' repo.

Then I create a new folder, where I added somes files and did :

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git remote add origin https://github.com/jozinho947/myRepo.git

# get the READ.me fetched on the 'origin/master' branch locally
git fetch

# get the READ.me merged in my local 'master' where i'm pointing
git merge origin/master
```

And then I have this error :

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I don't understand why I can't do this, and how to fix this.

Comment: Try cloning it first without having an existing repo. When you create a new repo it has a different history so git is refusing to combine the two without you saying it’s ok.

Comment: You can saying it’s ok by allowing unrelated histories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git refusing to merge unrelated histories on rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The remote copy of your repo has a root commit, with no parent -- the 1st commit with a `README.md` file.

With the actions you performed locally, your local repository also has a root commit with no parent.

`git merge` refuses to work because it cannot find a common ancestor to these two commits.

---

You probably want to replay your commits one after the other, use `git rebase` instead of `git merge` :

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This should apply your local root commit on top of the "README" commit.

---

If you want to replay them in the opposite order (remote commit on top of your local commit) : use `git cherry-pick origin/master`. You will then need to force push your master branch.

If you have good reason to keep two root commits in your repo : you can use the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option of `git merge`.

Comment: Exactly, thank you very much. As well, like 'mrmcgreg ' said above, i can just delete the existing local .git repo and git clone the remote.

Comment: Alternatively you might have said `git pull --rebase origin master`, but that is in fact the same as the given two step solution, `git fetch` followed by rebase.

Comment: same issue none worked for me this did... superb. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling with this git command `git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories`.

This should fetch the main branch from your remote repository and merge it with your local repo, afterwards you will push your code to the remote repository using the `git push -u origin main`.

You got that error message because a commit was made to the remote repository, like when you allowed Github to initialize a README file on your behalf.
But since your local repository is missing that README file, hence the message: `fatal refusing to merge unrelated branches`