# How to compare Git branches in CloudBuild?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-cloud-build

I've got a CloudBuild trigger setup listening to a bitbucket repository.  Once the build is complete, I've a cloud function which sends a slack message to the author of the commit.

The problem I have, is bitbucket triggers a `repo:push` on branch creation (though their UI).  This triggers a build, and then notifies the author of the last commit from the source branch that a new build is ready.

To prevent this, I decided to prevent the slack message triggering if the last commit on the triggered branch is also on master (the source branch).  I've tried this a number of ways, but it seems like the clone CloudBuild uses when triggered is NOT a full clone.  I can't quite work out what state the local repo is in... looks like maybe CloudBuild calls the branch `master` locally, no matter what branch triggered the build?  For example, commands like this:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
  - -c
  - |
    # Write the author name to the cloud build output
    git show -s --format='%ae' $COMMIT_SHA >> /builder/outputs/output
    # Write the latest commit to the output. 
    git rev-list ^master $COMMIT_SHA -1 >> /builder/outputs/output
```

Gives blank output, even when there are changes on `mybranch` that are not reachable by `master`.  The following similar command has the same result:

```
git log master..$COMMIT_SHA --oneline -1 >> /builder/outputs/output
```

Both of these commands correctly return the branch commits when I run locally.

If I add some explicit checkout steps like this (before the rev-list):

```
git checkout origin master
git checkout origin $BRANCH_NAME
```

I get this:

```
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/bitbucket_myproject_myrepo
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
* [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/bitbucket_myproject_myrepo
* branch            feature/mybranch -> FETCH_HEAD
* [new branch]      feature/mybranch -> origin/feature/mybranch
Already up to date.
```

Incidentially, this command

```
git log master..$BRANCH_NAME --oneline -1 >> /builder/outputs/output
```

throws this error

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..feature/mybranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

however, this command does not (but leaves me with the dreaded blank value):

```
git log master..$COMMIT_SHA --oneline -1 >> /builder/outputs/output
```

I'm super confused.  Can anyone help me with what exactly CloudBuild does when it does the `FETCHSOURCE` step?

```
FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/bitbucket_myproject_myrepo
* branch            1ed4397bd9825b3eb9fe8dca12409b06975a9c41 -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 1ed4397 some commit message
```

and how I can achieve my aim of getting a list of commits that appear only on my branch (not master)?

**--- UPDATED ---**

After @bhito suggested the shallow fetch, I've almost been able to reproduce locally, but there is still a difference I can't work out.  Doing the following locally works:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin myrepo
$ git fetch --depth 1 origin b72b37
$ git checkout FETCH_HEAD
$ git fetch --unshallow
$ git rev-list ^master feature/mybranch -1
fatal: bad revision '^master'
```

but then if I do this:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout feature/mybranch
$ git rev-list ^master feature/mybranch -1
```

it works!!  But only locally.  My reproduce is not quite right, since in the CloudBuild clone, when I try and checkout master I get:

```
Step #0 - "Setting deployment environment": Already on 'master'
```

It seems CloudBuild fetches the commit onto a branch called master... I'm not sure how and so can't figure out how to get back to where I can perform the `rev-list`

Comment: When you are listening to a trigger, Cloud Build will perform a copy of the commit only, to speed up the process. If you want to have full information of the repo, then you have to run `fetch --unshallow`. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers#including_the_repository_history_in_a_build) is the doc that explains it, hope that helps.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks @bhito, I knew it must be something like that.  Running the unshallow does appear to map the branches, but my `rev-list` command still, fails, and if I use the branch name with it, it still says `ambiguous argument 'feature/mybranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`.  I'm clearly missing the next step, do I need to checkout the branches too?  Feels weird.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase