# GitHub: how to re-open a pull request when the branch has no more history in common with master

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm playing with GitHub actions and testing a [commit linter](https://github.com/wagoid/commitlint-github-action) on a PR (from a dummy branch called `meh` to `master`), which I managed to make it work, except that I needed to change my previous commit messages (which were already pushed at that point) in order to match the commit linter regex (which uses conventional commit).

So I went with a `git rebase -i --root` and `reword`-ed every commit since the very beginning and then I pushed the commits to my branch `meh`, except that when I did that the PR closed automatically, I can't [reopen](https://github.com/kerry-perret/MessingUp/pull/4) or [create a new one (from the same branch `meh` to `master`)](https://github.com/kerry-perret/MessingUp/compare/master...meh) cause according to GitHub:

> The meh branch has no history in common with master.

How can I re-open my PR?

Comment: Not too surprised. I cloned your repo, and (on `master`) tried to do a `git merge meh` and it told me `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. If a merge would fail in this way, then a pull request can't make sense.

Comment: @alaniwi Yea and that's the reason why my question is how to fix that?

Comment: It seems that there is a non-default option called `--allow-unrelated-histories` which will allow the merge, so maybe you do that locally, commit to a new branch, push that new branch, and then do a PR from your new branch.

Comment: @alaniwi thanks will try this out, fingers crossed =|

Comment: Trying the merge with your actual repo gives a couple of merge conflicts to resolve, but it permitted the merge in principle.

Comment: More at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Comment: Too bad GitHub doesn't provide free pre-received hooks, I wanted to test how to modify already pushed stuff, that seems tricky to enforce such commit linting without having people fighting to rewrite the git history every now and then.

Comment: @alaniwi what worked for me to re-open the PR: `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`. Tbs, it kinda messed up the commit linter in fetching the commits. See: 
https://github.com/wagoid/commitlint-github-action/issues/36#issuecomment-647022955

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like what [@alaniwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13596037/alaniwi) said, this could be solved with what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396921/4636721):

> Try the following command:
>
> ```
> git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
> ```
>
> This should solve your problem.

That being said, you can also mess up the SHA1 of your commits at some point, if you have to `git push --force ...`, so yea it would work out to re-open the PR, but your CI might scream a little bit.