# git refusing while pull from upstream

Tags: gitlab

if I try to pull from origin this error I got: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`  and I tried this code also `git pull upstream branch --allow-unrelated-histories`  then I got conflict. **Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result**

Answer (score 0):

It is better to understand why you [have this message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65357156/6309).

But see if the issue persists if:

- you clone the repository
- switch to the right branch
- report your work in progress in that branch
- go on working on said branch (push/pull)

Comment: if I run this cmd ``` git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories``` this is the output.

Comment: @Alexmercer It is better to start again from  a new clone, rather than trying to fix the current local one: see if the issue persists in the new local clone.

Comment: CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in negentropy/hooks.py
Auto-merging negentropy/hooks.py
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in negentropy/fixtures/workflow_state.json
Auto-merging negentropy/fixtures/workflow_state.json
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in negentropy/fixtures/workflow_action_master.json
Auto-merging negentropy/fixtures/workflow_action_master.json
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in negentropy/fixtures/workflow.json
Auto-merging negentropy/fixtures/workflow.json
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: @Alexmercer Exactly. Clone again, and report your existing work in the new clone. No conflict that way.