# Trying to pull remote repo to local

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, nano

What I am trying to do was pull from remote repository to local. I had an issue with "refusing to merge unrelated histories.

I got an answer from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase). I wrote a command of `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` it took me from regular terminal window to the one in the picture.
In regular terminal when I push enter it was giving either an error or new line.
Now in this terminal window pushing enter button does not affect anything, page is same, I entered `^T` even though cannot move beyond this page.
Can anyone explain what kind of window it is, and how to commit and move beyond this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ukaD.png)

I tried writing `^T` and pushing enter button.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, it opened the `nano` editor. You have to press `Ctrl + O` to save and `Ctrl + X` to close the editor. In the lower bar, `^` means the `Ctrl` key, see also [save and exit nano](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52462).

Comment: worked thanks. In the background it was pulled actually, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+nano