# How can I insert all commit from an old GitHub repo into a new one?

Tags: github

I want to insert all the commits of one GitHub repo into a new one, so all the history is preserved.

So, I have a repo1 with commits A->B->C

And a repo2 with an initial commit D (without changes)

And I want to set repo2 to have commits as D->A->B->C

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git refusing to merge unrelated histories on rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before making the changes i would suggest you to make a backup or clone the repos. i usually do this in case anything goes wrong.

- Clone your repo2 to the local machine with `git clone` command. change the directory to repo2.
- Add repo1 to repo2 as `remote` repo.

```
git remote add repo1 <url_of_repo1>
```

- Then `fetch` the repo1 commits.

```
git fetch repo1
```

- Then `merge` all repo1 commits in repo2 (for commit history).

```
git merge repo1/main --allow-unrelated-histories
```

(Assuming your `branch name of repo1` as `main`)
The initial `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag is used to allow the merge of unrelated repositories and is used only when first merge.

- Resolve the conflicts if there are any. (by opening the conflict files) before merge of repo1 to repo2.

```
git commit -m "merge"
```

- Finally push the changes into repo2 with `git push origin main` command.
- commit SHA-1 hashes will be different in repo2 than they were in repo1. you can check that with `git reflog` command, it will show commit hashes.